# Continuity of the restriction of a function and Lusin's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $W$ be a bounded open set of $\mathbb{R}^{N}$, $N\geq2$, and $f$ a measurable function defined on $W$. We know that by Lusin's Theorem for all positive integer $k$ there exits a closed set $F_{k}\subset W$ such that the Lebesgue measure of the complement of $F_{k}$ is less that $ 1/k $ and the restriction of $f$ to $F_{k}$ is continuous. We now set $ F:=\cup_{n\geq1}\cap_{k\geq n}F_{k} $. Can we say that for all $a\in F$ there is an open neighborhood $V$ of $a$ and a constant $M$ such that $f$ is bounded by $M$ on $F\cap V$?

Comment: By "M", do you mean a constant does not depend on the choice of $a$

Comment: M is a constant that depends on the choice of a.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. Let $W=(0,1)\subset \Bbb R^1$. Define a function $f$ on $W$ as follows. Let $x\in W$. If $x$ is irrational, put $f(x)=0$. If $x$ is rational, put $f(x)=q$, where $x=p/q$ and the greatest common divisor of $p$ and $q$ is one. Then $f$ is measurable, but not locally bounded at any point $a\in W$.